# how to keep input field and delete his first parrent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have the following scenario: I want to append the input field to a different parent. The code looks like this

```
    <div id="id1">
        <div id="id2">
             <input type="radio">
       </div>
    </div>
```

I want to append the input field to "id1" and delete the "id2". The final result should look like this

```
    <div id="id1">
        <input type="radio">
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes, I did. what I am doing It's actually quite complicated. I am working on a HMTL5 page for mobile devices. I am using this script http://screwdefaultbuttons.com/ to add custom images to my page. However it is written I should use $(document).ready function but I actually have to replace it with $(document).bind('pageinit',function(){}); Now the problem is whenever a div with data-role=page is shown the script gets called again. The custom buttons are wrapped in a div that wraps the input field. each time I go to another page I get a deeper input field nested. I have to clean this somehow.

Comment: This is how it looks when I go to the next page. The input field gets nested two times. I want to place it just under the .ui-radio class. <div class="ui-radio"><div style="background-image: url(...);class="styledRadio"><div style="background-image: url(...); class="styledRadio"><input name="radiobuttons" data-role="none" type="radio" style="display: none; " onclick="..."></div></div><label for="..." type="radio">Bærbare computere</label></div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#id2 input').appendTo($('#id1'));
$('#id2').remove();
```

Comment: thanks. it looks like it works the way I want. But there is one little thing I have to figure out. I will come up with another question if I won't fixed it myself. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

```
​$('#id2 input').​​​​appendTo($('#id1'))​​​​;
$('#id2').remove();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MafhZ/)

Answer (score 1):

In one line:

```
​$("#id2"​​).find("input").appendTo("#id1"​).end().end().remove();​​​​​
```

Another one line:

```
​$("#id2 input"​​).unwrap("#id2");​​​​​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/CrmMG/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#id1').append($('#id2 input'))
$('#id2').remove();
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/67VYQ/2/)

Answer (score 0):

take your input

```
 var input =  $("inputselector");
```

Put it in desired container

```
var parentRef =  $("inputselector").parent();
 $("inputselector").parent().parent().append( $("inputselector"));
```

Delete parent

```
 parentRef.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$div = $('input:radio').clone();
$('#id2').remove();
$('#id1').append($div);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/D5rvT/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use either of them.

```
    $('#id2 input').​​​​appendTo($('#id1'))​​​​;
    $('#id2').remove();
    or
   $('#id2 input').unwrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery `unwrap()`. It removes the parent of selector leaving the selected element in it's place

```
$('#id2 input').unwrap()
```

API Reference  http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/